# Load image/css/js/webfonts locally from web-based mobile application

Tags: android, ios, uiwebview, webview, android-webview

I'm developing a web application, which the pages are completely rendered from server-side, And application loads the page with a `UIWebView`...

(The Url of that page is something like this: `http://mydomain.com/application/`)

Is there any way to load image/js/css/webfont files locally instead of downloading them in WebView (iOS/Android)?

*If it was PC instead of iOS/Android, I think I may use something like this in server-side rendered page:

```
<script src="file:///C:/Program%20Files/MyApp/Data/script.js"></script>
```

or

```
<img src="file:///C:/Program%20Files/MyApp/Data/welcome.png" />
```

(I think, but I'm not sure)

But how to do something like this in Mobile app ( iOS UIWebView / Android WebView )?

Comment: Do you make a webapp (pure) or is it web application in some sort of native wrapper (conventional native app for given platform with a webview)?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand what you said. My web application has a native UI, and It looks like a native application, while it is loading completely from the web. But, I just want to avoid downloading js/css/webfont/images every time that application starts. They should be cached locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a URI as the src in your html

"android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]"

```
<script src="android.resource://com.example.sample/raw/js_script">
```